# <code> tags are not rendering on the SE Status Blog

Tags: bug, design, blog

`<code>` tags currently do not have an appropriate style applied on the [SE Network Status Blog.](https://stackstatus.tumblr.com/post/147710624694/outage-postmortem-july-20-2016) It seems headings are not styled appropriately either.

> [image]

Comment: CNR on Firefox on Android: http://m.imgur.com/K85kRGK,CTASacK

Comment: It looks like this on Chrome and Safari on Mac (latter with no extensions).

Comment: Nvm, Can repro on WS2012R2 with Firefox: http://m.imgur.com/0ksWHHg

Comment: The normal stack blog runs on Jekyll (a markdown platform) whereas the Stack Status blog runs on Tumblr, so I'm assuming Tumblr posts don't support markdown (or code blocks)

Comment: @Quill ... but why do they show up on firefox android?